# Trying to remember the title of a zombie novel

Tags: story-identification, books, zombie, young-adult

In the last year or so I have read quite a few zombie novels (thinly disguised as book selection for work!)  There is one I would like to find again, but I cannot remember the title of it. I could also be conflating memories of different books!

Details I can remember:

- large amount of zombies "live" in an airport & on planes
- the main character is wearing a shirt and tie (which made me think of Plants vs Zombies!)
- he has a zombie wife, who leaves him for another zombie
- he is the narrator, and retains enough humanity to be able to narrate, though he can't remember his name

These points may be from a different novel:

- when he eats someone's brain, he gets flashes of their memories
- he infiltrates a closed city and meets a teenage girl, who is the girlfriend of someone he recently ate and he knows her from the boy's memory
- she disguises him as a human and lets him stay with her.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Warm Bodies*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1156483) by Isaac Marion, published in 2010. Soon to be a movie.

> R is having a no-life crisis—he is a zombie. He has no memories, no identity, and no pulse, but he is a little different from his fellow Dead. He may occasionally eat people, but he’d rather be riding abandoned airport escalators, listening to Sinatra in the cozy 747 he calls home, or collecting souvenirs from the ruins of civilization.
>
> And then he meets a girl.
>
> First as his captive, then his reluctant guest, Julie is a blast of living color in R’s gray landscape, and something inside him begins to bloom. He doesn't want to eat this girl—although she looks delicious—he wants to protect her. But their unlikely bond will cause ripples they can’t imagine, and their hopeless world won’t change without a fight.

Comment: Thank you very much! One of the better zombie books I read.  Will be interested to see what the movie turns out like.